# How to specify time format for php-fpm pool access.format

Tags: php-fpm

When configuring a PHP5-FPM pool, one can specify the format for all access log entries by setting the value for `access.format`.

The default provided `.conf` file stated:

> ```
> ;  %t: server time the request was received
> ;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
> ;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
> ;  %T: time the log has been written (the request has finished)
> ;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
> ;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
> ```

However, I searched high and low and cannot find any documentation as to how I can modify the `strftime` format for the `%t`/`%T` variables.

Can you provide me with an example on how I can change the format of the `%t`/`%T` variable to my liking?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where we log the time only:

```
access.format = "%R - %u %{%H:%M:%S}t \"%m %r\" %s"
```